# Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type 'CompletionHandler?' using KingFisher Swift

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

I am using a library called KingFisher to download image from internet.
For the reference:

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

https://cocoapods.org/pods/Kingfisher

`imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)`

This instruction works flawless but i wanted to track success so i added completion handler so the documentation suggestion this snippet.

```
imageView.kf.setImage(with: userInfo.getImageUrl()){ result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("success")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error) // The error happens
            }
        }
```

For the reference this is the cheat sheet i am using:

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet

On adding this snippet i am getting this compilation error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type 'CompletionHandler?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional, Optional, CacheType, Optional) -> ()>')

Comment: should be all optional, you need to remove the specified type

Comment: Even this is giving the same error:                          
        imageView.kf.setImage(with: userInfo.getImageUrl()){ result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let value):
                    print("success")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error) // The error happens
                }
            }

Comment: what version do you have installed? the completion handler error has a different definition than the one in the documentation

Comment: i am using 5.1 the link for 5.1 documentation has same code too

Comment: My version was actually 4.10.1 so went to its documentation and use that snippet and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift 4.2 Kingfisher 5.1**

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/high_resolution_image.png")
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: nil, options: nil, progressBlock: nil) { result in
    print(result)
    switch result {
    case .success(let value):
        print("success")
        print(value.source.url!)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error) // The error happens
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i am using KingFisher 5.1.0, i did not facing this kind of error. Please double check your podfile,

**pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.1.0'**

```
let url  = URL(string: "your image url")!

 self.kf.setImage(with: url) { result in
       switch result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("Image: \(value.image). Got from: \(value.cacheType)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

[https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet](http://Kingfisher%205.1.0%20Cheat%20sheet.)

if you are using the pod version lesser than 5.0, obvisouly you will be end up in getting

```
Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type 'CompletionHandler?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional, Optional, CacheType, Optional) -> ()>')
```

Comment: I did this in podfile pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.1.0' and pod update failed for some reason. My version was actually 4.10.1 so went to its documentation and use that snippet and it worked.

Comment: fine. if pod update failed, change the version to 5.1.0. then do pod deintegrate and pod install again. that will clear the local repo and pull the updated pod again.

Comment: I had a deployment target that was too old, updated, worked

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. I have been using Kingfisher 4.0.0 with Swift 4.

Changing to the following did the trick,

```
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: nil, options: nil, progressBlock: nil) { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in

}
```